# Re-implementing Matching Pennies

Tags: game-theory

I'm a little confused on a problem from my game theory course. I am reviewing
the standard ``matching pennies'' game where player $1$ wins $1$ and player $2$ loses $1$ if the their two pennies match and player $1$ loses $1$ and player $2$ wins $1$ if the their two pennies don't match. We can represent the game as this, where player $1$ has the rows and player $2$ has the columns:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    &\text{H}&\text{T} \\
    \hline
    \text{H}&1,-1&-1,1 \\
    \hline
    \text{T}&-1,1&1,-1 \\
    \hline
    \end{array}$$
Unfortunately, we know that this game does not have a pure strategy Nash
Equilibrium. However, we want to show that this game has a Nash Equilibrium
in the case of the sequential game where player $1$ moves first and player $2$
moves second. However I am having issues proving this in standard simultaneous
form. Does anyone have suggestions on how I might degenerate this sequential
form game to a simultaneous form?

Answer (score 0):

In the sequential game, player 1's pure strategies are $\{H,T\}$ and player 2's pure strategies are $\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$. So the strategic form of the game is

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &HH&HT&TH&TT \\\hline
H&\mathbf{1},-1&\mathbf{1},-1&\mathbf{-1},\mathbf{1}&-1,\mathbf{1}\\\hline
T&-1,\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{1},-1&\mathbf{-1},\mathbf{1}&\mathbf{1},-1\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
The best responses are boldfaced. We can therefore see the two pure NEs: $(H,TH)$ and $(T,TH)$. Player 1 gets $-1$ in both equilibria.